# How to bring variable from POST method

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, variables, post

I want to bring a variable from the login form, when inserted the login form redirects to /profile, this profile page is supposed to have the variable username from the login displayed in the page, like a session does with current user account being displayed... Yet tho, I haven't been able to render the page with the variable brought.. yet!

How do I do it?

Heres the code:

```
app.post('/login', function (req, res, next) {
    //console.log(req.body);
    const uri = "mongodb+srv://<USERNAME>:<PW>@<CLUSTER>.eapnyil.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
    const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, serverApi: ServerApiVersion.v1 });
    const users = client.db("data").collection("users");
    users.findOne({email:req.body.email},function(err,data){
        if(data){
            
            if(data.password==req.body.password){
                //console.log("Logged In.");
                console.log(data.email);
                console.log(req.body.email);
                //res.send({"Success":"Success!"});
                res.redirect('/profile');
            }else{
                res.send({"Success":"Wrong password!"});
            }
        }else{
            res.send({"Success":"This Email Is not registered!"});
        }
    });
});



app.get('/profile', function (request, response) {
    
    console.log("Fetching profile");
    const uri = "mongodb+srv://<USERNAME>:<PW>@<CLUSTER>.eapnyil.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
    const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, serverApi: ServerApiVersion.v1 });
    const users = client.db("data").collection("users");

    users.findOne({email:request.body.email},function(err,data){
        console.log(request.body.email);
        //response.render('pages/data', {users:username,users:email});
    })
});
```

On /profile this last bit of code 'users:username' seems to be undefined as far as I've managed..

```
...users.findOne({email:request.body.email},function(err,data){
        console.log(request.body.email);
        //response.render('pages/data', {users:username,users:email});
```

Comment: What's wrong with session?

Comment: I am not sure, just came across Session for the first time now.. Using this github (https://github.com/guruhariharaun/Registration-and-Login-Form-in-Nodejs-and-MongoDB/blob/master/routes/index.js) I got a bunch of errors, been fixing on my own via trial and error... I striped the export user.js out, am using collections so I don't need a schema, I guess

Comment: Instead of of ```response.render('pages/data', {users:username,users:email});```, try ```response.render('pages/data', {users:data.username,users:data.email});```, since the variable in the callback used is ```data```.

Answer (score 0):

redirect can have some query parameters so whatever the value you want in profile route 
just pass at the end of redirect as mentioned below

```
app.post('/login', function (req, res, next) {
    //console.log(req.body);
    const uri = "mongodb+srv://<USERNAME>:<PW>@<CLUSTER>.eapnyil.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
    const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, serverApi: ServerApiVersion.v1 });
    const users = client.db("data").collection("users");
    users.findOne({email:req.body.email},function(err,data){
        if(data){
            
            if(data.password==req.body.password){
                //console.log("Logged In.");
                console.log(data.email);
                console.log(req.body.email);
                //res.send({"Success":"Success!"});
                >> let query = JSON.stringify(req.body.email); || (data) //whatever value u need to send to profile route
                res.redirect('/profile?email='+query);
            }else{
                res.send({"Success":"Wrong password!"});
            }
        }else{
            res.send({"Success":"This Email Is not registered!"});
        }
    });
});



app.get('/profile', function (request, response) {
    
    >> let email = JSON.parse(request.query.email)
    console.log("Fetching profile");
    const uri = "mongodb+srv://<USERNAME>:<PW>@<CLUSTER>.eapnyil.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
    const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, serverApi: ServerApiVersion.v1 });
    const users = client.db("data").collection("users");

    users.findOne({email},function(err,data){
        console.log(request.body.email);
        //response.render('pages/data', {users:username,users:email});
    })
});
``
```